# xcode 9 I can not use the framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode9

In the sample program I added my framework to "**Link Binary With Libraries**".

I added it manually via Add Other because it was not the same workspace

It has been successfully added to the Frameworks category

Added to the Frameworks category, but if enter `#import <myFramework/header.h>` in `ViewController.m`, then file not found is printed.

`<myFramework...` No autocompletion.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the header public for the framework target membership? Is the header exported in `<myFramework/myFramework.h>` ?

Comment: yes <myFramework/header.h> is public, can check it in the sample program.